# Expanding Arcus Tangens as Taylor Series around 1: Symmetries

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series, functional-equations, symmetry

Expanding $\arctan$ around 0 as a Taylor series yields
$$
\arctan x = \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n\frac{x^{2n+1}}{2n+1}
$$
for $x$'s that are in the region of convergence.  All even terms vanish, which is due to the symmetry $\arctan (-x)=-\arctan x$, i.e. $\arctan$ is an odd function.

Now expanding around 1 (with radius of convergence $\sqrt2$) yields something like:

$$\begin{align}
\arctan(x+1) - \arctan(1) =&  \frac12x - \frac1{4}x^2 + \frac1{12}x^3 - \frac1{40}x^5 + \frac1{48}x^6 - \frac1{112}x^7 + \frac1{288}x^9 - \frac1{320}x^{10}\\
 & {} + \frac1{704}x^{11} - \frac1{1664}x^{13} + \frac1{1792}x^{14} - 
\frac1{3840}x^{15} + \frac1{8704}x^{17} - \frac1{9216}x^{18} + \frac1{19456}x^{19} \cdots
\end{align}$$
As you can see, every 4-th term vanishes, i.e. powers of $x$ with exponents of $0\bmod4$ do vanish.

**Questions**:

- What does this tell us about symmetries of $\arctan$ or any other function that shows such behaviour?
- Is there a straight forward way to see that every 4th term does actually vanish without carriying out fancy computations?

$\arctan$ satisfies $\arctan x+ \arctan(1/x)=\pi/2$, but I do not see how (or whether) this  symmetry has something to do with the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We have
$$
\frac{1}{(x + 1)^2 + 1} = \frac{1}{2i}\left(\frac{1}{(x + 1) - i} - \frac{1}{(x + 1) + i}\right),
\\
\arctan(x + 1)^{(n)} = c_n\left(\frac{1}{((x + 1) - i)^n} - \frac{1}{((x + 1) + i)^n}\right),\quad n\ge 0,
$$
where $c_n$ is a constant. For $x = 0$ the latter becomes $\displaystyle \frac{1}{(1 - i)^n} - \frac{1}{(1 + i)^n}$. This difference equals zero if $n$ is divisible by $4$ hence every 4th term in the Taylor series of $\arctan$ vanishes.

Comment: $\arctan(1+x)=\arctan 1+\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k\,x^k$, where
$$a_k=\frac{\arctan^{(k)}(1)}{k!}=\frac{(-1)^{k-1}}k\Im\frac1{(1-i)^k}=\frac{(-1)^{k-1}\sin\frac{\pi k}4}{k\,2^\frac k2},\quad k=1,2,3...$$

Answer (score 5):

Pavel Gubkin has answered your second question. To more explicitly address your first question: The oddness of a function, that is, the vanishing of coefficients of $x^n$ with $n$ a multiple of $2$, can be expressed as $f(x)+f(-x)=0$. This can be generalized to the vanishing of coefficients with $n$ a multiple of any integer $k$ as

$$
\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}f\left(\omega^j x\right)=0\;,
$$

where $\omega$ is any primitive $k$-th root of unity. Thus, with $\omega=\mathrm i$ a primitive fourth root of unity, the vanishing of the coefficients with $n$ a multiple of $4$ corresponds to the functional equation

$$
f(x)+f(\mathrm ix)+f(-x)+f(-\mathrm ix)=0
$$

(or a constant if the coefficient of $x^0$ doesn’t vanish). In this case,

$$
\arctan(1+x)+\arctan(1+\mathrm ix)+\arctan(1-x)+\arctan(1-\mathrm ix)=\pi\;.
$$

I was at first hoping to relate this to the other equation you mention, $\arctan x+\arctan\frac1x=\frac\pi2$, by writing that as

$$
\arctan\mathrm e^y+\arctan\mathrm e^{-y}=C\;,
$$

expressing the fact that $\arctan\mathrm e^y$ is an odd function up to a constant; but this doesn’t imply the vanishing of the coefficients with $n$ a multiple of $4$. For instance $x-\frac1x$ also has this property, but none of the coefficients in its series expansion at $x=1$ vanish.

By the way, $2(\arctan(1+x)-\arctan1)$ is the exponential generating function of [OEIS sequence A217260](https://oeis.org/A217260), which is the [series reversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_inversion_theorem) of [OEIS sequence A000111](https://oeis.org/A000111), the [Euler numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_numbers).

Comment: Thank you. So the last part also explains why the expansion is alternating with coefficents that are reciprocals of integers.

Comment: @emacsdrivesmenuts: Why is that?

Comment: Oops, missed a `?` at the end of my comment queston.